# How to end scrolling of Webview 300 dps from end of Webview (or end of web page)? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-scroll, webchromeclient

I am unable to edit some footers on my web page and therefore would like to hide the web page footer by not allowing the user to scroll there. 
I have the following Webview;

```
            myWebView.loadUrl(value);
            myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress1) {
                    MyActivity.setProgress(progress1 * 100);
                }
            });

            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
                public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                }
            });
             myWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            //Doing stuff here
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            //Doing stuff here
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to disable scrolling when the user reaches the final 300 dps or so of his screen size. 
I would also like some clarification on whether using both the `setWebChromeClient` and `setWebViewClient` like mentioned above is okay. If yes, which client would the Android device pick?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by storing the web page HTML contents to a string and then parsing and displaying it using;

myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Hope this helps someone.